# Ida Pro Calling the internal debuggers via Python script

Tags: python, debugging, ida

Is there some way to call the internal remote gdb debugger via python in the IDA Pro environment? Note that I am referring to situations in which the process doesn't already have a debugger attached, and I would like to call the remote gdb debugger and attach it.

Answer (score 2):

Well i figured it out.
I have made a python script that loads on startup.

```
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("windbg_user.plw", 0)
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("armlinux_stub.plw", 0)
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("gdb_user.plw", 0)
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("linux_stub.plw", 0)
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("mac_stub.plw", 0)
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("win32_stub.plw", 0)
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("win32_user.plw", 0)
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("wince_stub.plw", 0)
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("bdescr.plw", 0)
idaapi.load_and_run_plugin("epoc_user", 0)
idc.LoadDebugger("gdb", 1)
```

last one is bringing the gdb debugger to front, its not really needed.